# How to change state in a hook from an outside function in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have to make a few changes in a project and i'm not really familiar with react. How can i change the state of a Hook from an outside function? This is what i have:

```
export const HomeView = () => {

[...]

const ProductDetails = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);
  const [currentPrice, setCurrentPrice] = React.useState(5);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {


      // get available items and current price when page loads
      [...]
      const number = 15;

      setNumber(number);

      [...]

      const currentPrice = 10;

      setCurrentPrice(currentPrice);
    
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);

  // returns available items and current price with a button to buy

     return (
         <div >
         <h2>Current price : {currentPrice} </h2>
         <button onClick={() => buyProduct({currentPrice})}>
           "Click me"
         </button>
         <h2>Available {number} / 10000</h2>
       </div>
     );


const buyProduct = async ({currentPrice}: {currentPrice: number;}) => {

  //users buys product, refresh available number
  [...]

  const number = 14;

  //each time a buy occurs, i have to increase price

  const currentPrice = 11;

  //How do i pass this new data to update the data in ProductDetails when a buy occurs without 
  //refreshing the whole page from the browser?

};

return (
  <div >
    [...]
    <ProductDetails />
    [...]
  </div>
);
```

I thought about moving the hook from ProductDetails inside the whole HomeView, but i don't really know how the whole process will work since i'm not that familiar with react. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is not recommended.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions

> Only Call Hooks from React Functions
> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:

- Call Hooks from React function components.
- Call Hooks from custom Hooks

By following this rule, you ensure that all stateful logic in a component is clearly visible from its source code.

However, you can pass an internal function as a parameter which will update the state to the method buyProduct which will update the state number and currentPrice using setNumber & setCurrentPrice respectively and call it within buyProduct itself.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, tried your solution but i can't seem to implement it. Mind sharing some code? Thanks

Comment: Hey, @CosminVacaru Sorry for the delayed response. Have you fixed the problem. I think you can easily create an arrow function as follows : 
`const  buyProduct = ({{currentPrice}: {currentPrice: number;}})=>{ 
//remaining code
}` 
Please let me know how it goes.